# AEM issue in dialog of carousel component

Tags: aem

I am a AEM developer, I have a issue in dialog of multifield. In carousel component(out of the box component) when we trying to add in the fixed list using path field, the selected path of image is saved if we click save. If u click cancel button and again trying to add image in the path field it is not getting added it is showing error.

I have tried to find a solution but we need to make changes in `dialog.js` I need a solution tat if i click the cancel button the dialog should not the save the things and it should open freshly again when the author opens again.